# How to fix this in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, error

> Circular dependency: Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsCollector depends
>   on Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address and vice versa.

Comment: Did you try after deleting var folder ?

Comment: I tried after deleting var folder have this same issue? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2.1 I see that `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsCollector` is injected in `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address`. But not vice versa.
So which version are you using?
Did you change the code?
What did you change?

To fix well obviously remove the circular dependency...

Comment: I have use Magento 2.2.2. I did not change any code in core side.

Comment: I don't see it in 2.2.2 either. Do you have the full error message?